# How to iterate on files in a directory robustly and portably, oldest first?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, posix, busybox

"Robustly" -- I'm trying to handle files with spaces and newlines and other special characters in the file names -- only because I've seen some special characters despite being told my target environment wouldn't have them.

"Portably" -- needs to run on a wide variety of Linux machines, including BusyBox.

"Oldest" -- by modification time, with names as a tiebreaker would suffice for my purpose.

Normally I'd use `find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' 2>/dev/null | sort | cut -d' ' -f2 | while read filename; do mything "$filename"; done`

But on this particular BusyBox v1.18.4 `find` does not support `-printf` so I'm  not sure I can use `find` to expose the modification times for sorting.

```
Usage: find [PATH]... [EXPRESSION]

Search for files. The default PATH is the current directory,
default EXPRESSION is '-print'

EXPRESSION may consist of:
-follow     Follow symlinks
-xdev       Don't descend directories on other filesystems
-maxdepth N Descend at most N levels. -maxdepth 0 applies
        tests/actions to command line arguments only
-mindepth N Don't act on first N levels
-name PATTERN   File name (w/o directory name) matches PATTERN
-iname PATTERN  Case insensitive -name
-path PATTERN   Path matches PATTERN
-regex PATTERN  Path matches regex PATTERN
-type X     File type is X (X is one of: f,d,l,b,c,...)
-perm NNN   Permissions match any of (+NNN), all of (-NNN),
        or exactly NNN
-mtime DAYS Modified time is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
        or exactly N days
-mmin MINS  Modified time is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
        or exactly N minutes
-newer FILE Modified time is more recent than FILE's
-inum N     File has inode number N
-user NAME  File is owned by user NAME (numeric user ID allowed)
-group NAME File belongs to group NAME (numeric group ID allowed)
-depth      Process directory name after traversing it
-size N[bck]    File size is N (c:bytes,k:kbytes,b:512 bytes(def.))
        +/-N: file size is bigger/smaller than N
-links N    Number of links is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
        or exactly N
-print      Print (default and assumed)
-print0     Delimit output with null characters rather than
        newlines
-exec CMD ARG ; Run CMD with all instances of {} replaced by the
        matching files
-prune      Stop traversing current subtree
-delete     Delete files, turns on -depth option
(EXPR)      Group an expression
```

And I read that looping over the output of `ls` is a bad idea.

My environment also does not support `stat -c format` but I can use `stat -t` ...

So my current idea is to

```
cd "$1"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    printf 'failed cd'
    exit 1
fi

while read name
do
    mything "$name"
done <<< "$(stat -t ./*                \
    | awk -F' ' '{print $13 " " $1}' \
    | sort -r                        \
    | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')"
```

Is there a better way? I'm relying on stat's 'terse' format being consistent.

Comment: A robust POSIX sh implementation is possible, but it's not *at all* fast. Do you have `stat -c` support in your build of busybox?

Comment: It's interesting that you explicitly define "robustly" and "portably", but fail to explain what you mean by "oldest".  Most file systems do not record the creation time of the file, so "oldest" is problematic.

Comment: Found the source here -- https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/5bbee27c0fcafe60f43a294afa1352b5ddcab6f3/coreutils/stat.c -- and `FEATURE_STAT_FORMAT` is an optional flag, so the answer here will depend on the compile-time options used for your particular busybox build.

Comment: BTW, `for f in $(find ...)` is not at all robust. See [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) (though it's not particularly helpful in this specific use case).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy indeed `stat -c fmt` is supported on this box. You're right about compile time options. If a solution given this particular `find` and/or `stat -c fmt` that is otherwise also POSIX turns out to be insufficient, I can always address it later. ... @William Pursell, modification time is fine for my purpose -- I didn't completely fail to mention it (cf using printf to expose modification time ;)

Comment: @user3735178, one can't *only* go on mtime -- mtime can be identical between two different files, so one needs a second-order sort criteria for that case. If you *really* want the pure POSIX approach I can write it up, but it's a horrible O(n^2) atrocity you'd never want to actually *use*. Much better to take advantage of `stat -c`, since you have it.

Comment: If the second-order choice were random that wouldn't be so bad in my case. The second-order choice could be smallest first (and still have a tie).

Comment: random doesn't work without making the algorithm stateful (so it can track which files it has and hasn't previously seen), which isn't as easy in POSIX sh as it would be in a shell with associative arrays. I suppose one could do mtime -> size -> name.

Comment: How do you _describe_ machines that don't have `stat -c`?  I can ask around to see if that's a concern here.

Comment: I'd describe such systems as "baseline POSIX", since `stat -c` isn't POSIX-defined.

Comment: Alas, there is a box where `stat` usage is `stat [-l] [-f] [-v] [-t] file1 [file2 ...]`